# How to change the active layer in QGIS Console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want my script to perform actions on a particular layer.  Online advice I've found so far suggests using the iface method "setActiveLayer()".  Makes sense based on the name alone.

Scenario:  In the Layers window I have a layer named "Province" highlighted (active).  Then I run the following code:

```
>>> vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer( 'na_roads_Prov' )
>>> iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

Console Output = False

As far as I understand executing this code in the console should move the highlighted "active layer" from "Province" to 'na_roads_Prov'.  Yes?  Instead the "Province" layer remains highlighted as active, and the console output says "False".  Any ideas?  Am I not referring to the layer correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mapLayersByName` method to get the layer by name

```
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('na_roads_Prov')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Much appreciated!  I see the original method I was trying to use, "mapLayer", requires the layer ID.  Out of curiosity I've tried locating the layer ID by looking at the layer properties, and also by typing into the following into the console...        layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.getLayerID()       BUT... the result is as follows... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'getLayerID'        Any easy way to find a layer's ID?  Thank you.

Comment: layer.id() will get you the id.

Comment: Also, presumably you can use "mapLayersByName" to set multiple layers to the instance pointer at the same time?  Can you show me the correct syntax for two layers?  If you'd like I can pose this as a stand alone question.  Thank you.

Comment: Layer names are not unique in QGIS so you can have many layers return from that same function call. e.g you could have 3 x `na_roads_Prov` in your project. Why. No idea but you can.

Comment: A basic question as I´m not a programmer: how to use that code _layer.id()_? I suppose if paste in Python console it gives me the id of the layer, right? But gives me error...

Answer (score 6):

For QGIS3 this functionality seems to be mapped to `QgsProject` now:

```
# I get the layer object by the name 'na_roads_Prov'
roads = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('na_roads_Prov')[0]
# I select the layer object
iface.setActiveLayer(roads)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  On a side note, do you know how to script the same thing in ArcMap?

Comment: @Waterman no, I do not