# QGIS 3 set the active layer

Tags: qgis-3, layers, python-3

I need to select a specific layer in the layer tree before I run my python script.
I have tried
[Activating layer by its name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165415/activating-layer-by-its-name-in-pyqgis/165426#165426)
 with the code

```
registry = QgsProject.instance()
layer = registry.mapLayersByName("name")[0]
```

but on the layer tree, there is no change of focus. The layer does not get selected. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `iface.setActiveLayer(layer)`. A similar question was asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167695/how-to-change-the-active-layer-in-qgis-console).

Comment: This is perfect!